# Testing methods that behaves like getter/setters but are more like factories

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, factory

Let's say I have a small class that handles connections to MySQL databases:

```
class myDatabaseHandler{

  private $_databases;

  public function addDatabase($name, $dsn, $username, $password){
     $this->_databases[$name] = array('dsn' => $dsn, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password);
     return true;
  }

  public function getDatabase($name){

     $connectionInfo = $this->_databases[$name];
     $database = new Database($connectionInfo['dsn'], $connectionInfo['username'], $connectionInfo['password']);

     $database->doSomeSetup();
     $database->attachMoreThings();

     return $database;
  }
}
```

I want to unit test these 2 methods:

```
class myDatabaseHandlerTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testAddDatabase(){

    }

    public function testGetDatabase(){

    }
}
```

How can this I test those 2 methods? If I `addDatabase()`, at most it would return a `Boolean` telling me the operation succeeded. Since it writes to a private property, I cannot confirm that the correct data is indeed written to it.

I feel that using `getDatabase()` to get a Database object back and testing against it is not exactly ideal, because I would need to expose `dsn`, `username` and `password` just for the sake of testing. In addition, it is possible that the `Database` object might modify those values to a format it uses, so I need to store the original values just for testing.

What is the best way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Testing certainly gets tricky when you try to construct *and* use an object in the same place. In this case, you are both constructing a `Database` and calling methods on it in your `getDatabase($name)` method. That makes it pretty much impossible to mock, for instance, and to get decent coverage your tests would need to test the functionality provided by the `Database` class to make sure the system was behaving as expected.

A better way might be using a proper factory as a dependency.

```
interface iDatabaseFactory 
{
    public function buildDatabase($dsn, $username, $password);
}
```

Then, you could mock both the database factory and the database instance itself to verify that it is both constructed correctly and initialized correctly:

```
class MockDatabaseFactory implements iDatabaseFactory
{
    public $databaseParams = array();
    public $databaseToReturn = NULL;

    public function buildDatabase($dsn, $username, $password)
    {
        $this->databaseParams['dsn'] = $dsn;
        $this->databaseParams['username'] = $username;
        $this->databaseParams['password'] = $password;
        return $this->databaseToReturn;
    }
}

class myDatabaseHandlerTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testAddAndGetDatabaseUsesCorrectDbParameters(){
        $mockDatabaseFactory = new MockDatabaseFactory();
        $dbHandler = new myDatabaseHandler($mockDatabaseFactory);

        // implement MockDatabase according to your interface
        $mockDatabase = new MockDatabase(); 
        $mockDatabaseFactory->databaseToReturn = $mockDatabase;

        $dbHandler.addDatabase("some name", "some dsn", 
                               "some username", "pa$$w0rd");
        $builtDatabase = $dbHandler.getDatabase("some name");

        $this->assertEquals($mockDatabase, $builtDatabase);
        $dbParams = $mockDatabaseFactory->databaseParams;
        $this->assertEquals("some dsn", $dbParams['dsn']);
        $this->assertEquals("some username", $dbParams['username']);
        $this->assertEquals("pa$$w0rd", $dbParams['password']);
    }

    public function testAddAndGetDatabaseInitializesDb(){
        $mockDatabaseFactory = new MockDatabaseFactory();
        $dbHandler = new myDatabaseHandler($mockDatabaseFactory);

        $mockDatabase = new MockDatabase();
        $mockDatabaseFactory.setDatabaseToBuild($mockDatabase);

        $dbHandler.addDatabase("name", "dsn", "user", "pass"); 
        $builtDatabase = $dbHandler.getDatabase("some name");

        $this->assertTrue($mockDatabase->doSomeSetupWasCalled);
        $this->assertTrue($mockDatabase->attachMoreThingsWasCalled);
    }
}
```